# How to use assertion in main method

Tags: java, selenium

I am verifying my login assertions through selenium webdriver and i have two classes in two different packages one is my page class and second one is my Test class. My code is working fine if i am using in page class but when i'm using assertionequals in my Testclass method it fails.

```
        //To verify login of uat seller
        WebElement useremail1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']"));
        WebElement Sign_in = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn-signin']"));
        useremail1.sendKeys("alicatalogtest@mailinator.com");
        password.sendKeys("XXX");
        Sign_in.click();
        String actualurl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        String expectedurl="https://uat-seller.yayvo.com/products/dashboard";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualurl,expectedurl);
```

Comment: Try printing out `actualurl` and `expectedurl`. What does it show? Is it possible that actualurl ends with a '/'?

Comment: What is the exception message you are getting when the test fails?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you might be getting `NullPointer Exception`. Basically, you have to use class name before the `String`, for Example, if `actualurl` is in page class then `Page.actualurl`. And your String should be `public` and `static` then only you can use it in another class.

Or you can extend the page class but this doesn't work if you have multiple classes.